# Shortcut URL gives other result than opening Chrome and browsing to URL

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

I'm with a major problem with the developer of a web product design tool.
We have for about 200 shops running on this tool. So to help our shop we create a desktop shorcut through Google Chrome to open our tool direclty.
But when we do that, the tool is not working correclty.
When we start Google Chrome and open the URL the tool works perfectly.

What can be wrong because it's very strange that the tool isn't completely running when opening from a desktop shortcut.

Comment: you need to provide much more detaiks

Comment: is the url definitely the same ... what about it doesn't work?